# Missing method id attribute in generated WADL with ServiceMix 7 M3 and CXF

Tags: cxf, wadl, apache-servicemix

We are using ServiceMix 7.0.0.M3 and use the CXF WADL generator.
Now the generated WADL does not seem to have a 'id' attribute in the resource>method tags. For example, the 4th line in the following WADL does not have an 'id' attribute.

```
<resources base="http://localhost:8181/api/rest/box">
   <resource path="/">
      <resource path="boxes">
         <method name="GET">
            <request>
               <param name="language" style="header" type="xs:string"/>
               <param name="includeInactive" style="query" type="xs:boolean"/>
            </request>
            <response>
               <representation mediaType="application/json;charset=utf-8" element="prefix1:BoxRestResponse"/>
            </response>
         </method>
      </resource>
```

If I would have the WADL generated with Jersey, I would get an 'id' property, containing the name of the corresponding Java method.

```
<resources base="http://localhost:8181/api/rest/box">
   <resource path="/">
      <resource path="boxes">
         <method name="GET" id="getBoxes">
            <request>
               <param name="language" style="header" type="xs:string"/>
               <param name="includeInactive" style="query" type="xs:boolean"/>
            </request>
            <response>
               <representation mediaType="application/json;charset=utf-8" element="prefix1:BoxRestResponse"/>
            </response>
         </method>
      </resource>
```

One of our frontend development tools expects the 'id' attribute to be present.

Is it possible to configure the CXF WADL generator to include the method id attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The id's are generated when adding the WadlGenerator configuration property 'addResourceAndMethodIds' to the CXF Blueprint file:

```
   <bean id="wadlGenerator" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator">
        <!-- properties: Method Summaries @ https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/model/wadl/WadlGenerator.html -->
        <property name="linkJsonToXmlSchema" value="true" />
        <property name="useJaxbContextForQnames" value="true" />
        <property name="addResourceAndMethodIds" value="true" />
    </bean>
```